# How to get more extension shortcut flexibility in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

In the newest Google Chrome version, as of May 5th, 2018, there is very little flexibility for shortcuts to open a Chrome extension.

In the chrome://extensions menu, you can click on the menu bar icon which will open the 'Keyboard Shortcuts' page. The problem: there is very little flexibility in the options. For example, you can only use one of (control/command/alt) at once.

Is there a way to add more flexibility to these commands, like maybe allowing for more than one (control/command/alt) key to be used at once? I'm pretty sure that it worked in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

On the Chrome toolbar
click on the ‘+” sign to open a new tab
left click on the “3” vertical dots at the far right with your mouse
when the menu opens, click on “settings”
the “search” bar will show a “navy blue chrome Icon”   followed by the word “Chrome”, a vertical line, then chrome://settings

the menu that opens up after left or right clicking with your mouse on the word “settings” brings up a new menu that starts with the word “People” as a heading, followed by a vertical list starting with your Google sign in that shows “Syncing to XXXXXXX@gmail.com”, etc. (see pic)

From this list, click on the “Passwords” word
Now you will see in the “address/search bar”: “Chrome | chrome://settings/passwords”

From here you take your mouse and left click and “Hold” on the nave blue chrome icon in the “address/search bar”.

“DRAG” that “navy blue chrome icon” to your toolbar where you have your “other” shortcuts and
VOILA !

YOU NOW HAVE A SHORTCUT TO YOUR PASSWORDS RIGHT ON YOUR TOOLBAR…

…it will now show a “navy blue ‘settings’ icon” with the word “Settings” next to it.